# What is the correct scope of DAF pipeline servlet

Tags: atg

What is the correct scope for a DAF pipeline servlet component used for REST services (like ActorServlet)? Should it be set to global or request?

Answer (score 2):

From the ATG Documentation:

> If a component’s $scope property is not explicitly set, it automatically has global scope.

Looking at the `ActorServlet` in the Component Browser in `dynadmin` it shows that there is no explicit scope set so it should indicate it is `global` scope by default.

Looking into this a bit more, the `ActorServlet` (which is the component of the `RestPipelineServlet`) extends the the `PipelineableServletImpl` which implements the `PipelineableServlet` interface. Here there is an abstract method `passRequest` which forms part of the actual pipeline 'chain' being executed.

```
public abstract void passRequest(ServletRequest paramServletRequest, ServletResponse paramServletResponse)
throws IOException, ServletException;
```

This means you will always have access to the current `request`. In the `PipelineableServletImpl` it internally calls the `service` method.

```
public void service(DynamoHttpServletRequest pRequest, DynamoHttpServletResponse pResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //Insert your logic here
    passRequest(pRequest, pResponse);
}
```

You would normally override the `service` method and add your own logic in there but still have access to the *current* `request` which should indicate to you that, as long as the rest of your variables are thread safe, specifying your Pipeline Servlet as `global` scope is the correct way to go.